# Finding the missing number given the AM of the remaining numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A number $m$ is erased from a list of $1$ ~ $n$ integers. The arithmetic mean of the remaining $n-1$ numbers is $\frac{119}{3}$. Find $m$.

It is a question from a high school problem-solving contest.

In the question, $1$ ~ $n$ integers means listing the first $n$ natural numbers in order, for example: $n=6$ => $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: Have you made a start on the problem? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the remaining $n-1$ numbers is $\frac{119}{3}(n-1)$. This gives the equation $\frac{119}{3}(n-1) + m = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, or $ m = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{119}{3}(n-1)$.

Solve the quadratic equation for $n$ and there are two roots. Since $m > 0$, there are no solutions in between the two roots, and to the left of the smaller root, there is one solution that does not make sense.

Therefore, we have to look for solutions greater than the $x$-coordinate of the largest root. We now use the condition $n ≥ m$, which gives us an upper bound on $m$.

This reduces to only a few numbers to check, which gives the solution:
  $m = 66, n = 79$.

Comment: The sum of $1+\dots+n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my answer.